# Sorting table with jQuery how to

Tags: jquery, html

I know there are a lot of plugins for table sorting, but I would like to learn it myself. So here is my table.

```
<table class="table-bordered sortable">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Wage</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jack Carver</td>
      <td>368</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Johnson</td>
      <td>450</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>Atlanta</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Steve McKenzie</td>
      <td>891</td>
      <td>88</td>
      <td>Miami</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

How can I make my table sortable? If user clicks on th, relevant tds should be sort alphabetically (and rest of row as well).

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general approach. No one step is particularly difficult, it's just sometimes hard to put everything together:

1. Bind an event handler to each of the `<th>` elements
2. This event handler will need to look at all of the `<tr>` elements, and put those into an array.
3. Sort the `<tr>` elements with [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). The sorting function will need to look at the contents of `<td>` child element of the `<tr>` passed in with the same index as the `<th>` element clicked.
4. Clear the `<tbody>` and reinsert the `<tr>`s in the sorted order.
5. Add some sort of indicator to the `<th>` to indicate that it is sorted.

Now I wouldn't use the result of this technique in production because it is quite fragile and we shouldn't be manipulating DOM directly in this fashion, but at least it is a good exercise to develop JS skills.

Comment: What kind of technique you would use for production?